# How to adjust table within table to have single border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table in HTML (new to it).

There is a heading and subheading in between, but its border get misaligned, when i create table within table.

also, border of ticket-status cell should match with three cell (Pending, Cancelled, Total), but border is not aligning accordingly.

You can check following check code for more clarification and also fiddle for immediate look into the look and feel of border.

Could anyone please help how can i resolve this.

Following is code:

```
<div>
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="30%">
            <col width="30%">
                <col width="20%">
                    <col width="20%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Ticket Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Quota People</th>
            <th scope="col">Quota People</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%">
            <col width="5%">
                <col width="10%">
                    <col width="10%">
                        <col width="10%">
                            <col width="10%">
                                <col width="10%">
                                    <col width="10%">
                                        <col width="10%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Unit Name</th>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Pending</th>
            <th scope="col">Cancelled</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
            <th scope="col">Sports</th>
            <th scope="col">VIP</th>
            <th scope="col">Sports</th>
            <th scope="col">VIP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Finland Railways</td>
            <td>210</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjkofLmp/

Comment: nb. With regards to your last request, there is a close reason for questions regarding `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: @SW4:
Removed that question. But i feel, it should be there as it is helpful for newbie and developers to have comments from experts here.

Comment: Indeed, but it is outside the scope of SO and may attract negative attention as a result, which detracts from providing a solution to the code-related question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add [**`border-collapse`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

> The border-collapse CSS property determines whether a table's borders
> are separated or collapsed. In the separated model, adjacent cells
> each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed model, adjacent
> table cells share borders.

### [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjkofLmp/2/)

By extension, you can simplify your markup to use a single table with two header rows, and `colspan` instead of `colgroup`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Ticket Status</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="3">Quota People</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="4">Quota People</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Unit Name</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Pending</th>
      <th scope="col">Cancelled</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col">Sports</th>
      <th scope="col">VIP</th>
      <th scope="col">Sports</th>
      <th scope="col">VIP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Finland Railways</td>
      <td>210</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. An additional question: Like you see in HTML; the border of ticket-status cell should match with outer border of three cell (Pending, Cancelled, Total), but border is not aligning accordingly. Could you please also help in that?

Comment: Simplify your markup- and use `colspan` not `colgroup`: https://jsfiddle.net/hjkofLmp/3/